# Working RAID 1 returns “ERROR: pdc: wrong # of devices in RAID set”

Tags: raid, ubuntu-gnome, mdadm

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 LTS 64-bits.

I have made with `mdadm` a RAID 1 with 2 2-TB-disks for normal storage (without any OS nor bootloader), which are `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` (both with exactly the same partition size: 1.8 TB). The `/` partition is in `/dev/sdc1` so I don't think it will affect.

Both seem to work perfectly since I have stored about 120 GB without any problem, `cat /proc/mdstat` still returns this:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      1932603392 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

The problem is, that every time I run `update-grub`, it returns these "ERRORs":

```
ERROR: pdc: wrong # of devices in RAID set "pdc_cjdebbggeg" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
ERROR: pdc: wrong # of devices in RAID set "pdc_cjdebbggeg" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
```

I wouldn't like to lose any of my stored data, so... What should I do? Should I leave them as long they seem to work fine? Or mark `/dev/sdb1` as "fail", detach, format somehow and reattach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is grub installed?

Comment: @ElderGeek GRUB was installed in `/dev/sdc`, an independient drive

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like its complaining about just having the wrong number of devices in your RAID array. RAID 1 is simply mirroring a single hard drive. Can you reinstall and rearrange things so you have a single disk being mirrored to the second?

Comment: I have just installed it, with only 2 devices in RAID 1. And it actually is mirroring the first one to the second, it is working fine. But the error is still there.